# Inconsistent behavior of ElasticSearch not_analyzed field

Tags: elasticsearch, bigdata

I am using ES version 2.3. I have index some documents which have the structure like this :

```
{
"BUSINESSLINE" :"ABC CORP",
"NAME" : "John"
....
...
}
```

The field BUSINESSLINE is not_analyzed string.

The problem is that this query returns results :

```
 {
      "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
          "query":    "ABC", 
          "fields": [ "_all" ] 
        }
      }
    }
```

But this one does not (It shows no hits!):

```
{
      "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
          "query":    "ABC", 
          "fields": [ "BUSINESSLINE " ] 
        }
      }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, I tried to google and research but I am not able to able find any reason for this.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you check whether any other field in the document contains this(`ABC` or `abc` or `Abc`) word?

Comment: No, it matches on BUSINESSLINE, i cannot share the _source here, but I can clearly see that it matches on "BUSINESSLINE"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. The query matches the document because of `_all` filed which is a big string constructed by concatenating all fields by the space separator. And it is also `analysed` which is why your query is being matched.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#mapping-all-field).